# How to saprate break this text "?#sid52985020" in my xml file and add to last

Tags: html, xml, xslt

How to sap-rate break this text "?#sid52985020" in my xml file and add to last

Here is my code:

```
<xsl:variable name="gatracker1">?intenttarget=no&amp;</xsl:variable>

<a target="_blank"">
<xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="alink"/><xsl:value-of select="$gatracker1"/></xsl:attribute>
</a>
```

XML code:

```
<alink>http://www.rohitazad.com/tax-return/newslist/51507984.cms?#sid52985020 </alink>
```

I want to result like this

```
"http://rohitazad.com/tax-return/newslist/51507984.cms?intenttarget=no&amp#sid52985020"
```

Comment: Please always post a [mcve] **and** explain the logic of the required transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="gatracker1">?intenttarget=no&amp;</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="alink">
    <a target="_blank">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '?#')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$gatracker1"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '?#')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

This is assuming you want to insert the variable at the location of the first `?#` in the given link.

Note that your result has `http://rohitazad.com/` but in the source it is `http://www.rohitazad.com`.